# Poisson process and uniform distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, stochastic-processes

**Question:**

> A single-pump petrol station is running low on petrol. The total
>   volume of petrol remaining for sale is $100$ litres.
>
> Suppose cars arrive to the station according to a Poisson process with
>   rate $\lambda$, and that each car fills independently of all other
>   cars and of the arrival process, an amount of petrol that is
>   distributed as a uniform random variable over $(0, 50)$ - assume for
>   example that all car tanks have a capacity of $50$ litres and drivers
>   decide "at random" when to refill.
>
> We assume that service is instantaneous so that there are no queues at
>   the station.
>
> **(a)** On average, how many cars will the petrol station fully service
>   (sell the full amount requested) before it runs out of petrol (and
>   before any refilling occurs)?
>
> **(b)** How much time will it take on average before the station runs out
>   of petrol (and before any refilling occurs)?

---

Attempt at part **(a)**:

I don't think I need to use the assumption that cars arrive according to a Poisson process in this part. So, define $U_k$ as the random variable that denotes the amount of petrol that car $k$ fills, $k = 1, 2, 3, \cdots$. Thus, $U_k, k = 1, 2, 3, \cdots$ are independently and identically distributed as a uniform random variable over $(0,50)$.

Let $N$ be the random variable that denotes the number of cars that the petrol station can *fully* service.

Now I don't quite get the question. Say we have the following scenario:

Car 1 comes with 10L remaining in its tank, so it will fill up 40L, hence the amount of petrol left in the station is now 100-40 = 60L.

Car 2 comes with 10L remaining in its tank, so it will fill up 40L, hence the amount of petrol left in the station is now 60-40 = 20L.

Car 3 comes with 20L remaining in its tank, so it will fill up 30L, but the petrol station only has 20L left, so does this mean Car 3 just leaves the petrol station filling 0L? My gut feeling is that this cannot happen because each car can only fill an amount BETWEEN 0 and 50, ie, (0,50) [note that the end points are not included].

Hence in this scenario, the petrol station runs "out" of petrol at N=3 because it does not have enough to FULLY service Car 3, even though it still has 20L left in the pump. Thus, the petrol station can only service N=2 cars.

Is this interpretation correct? If so, how do I find $E[N]$?

---

EDIT: working on further...

Define $G_N = \sum_{k=1}^N U_k$, then $E[N] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n P(N=n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n P(G_n \le 100)$

This equivalence comes from the fact that the event $\{N=n\}$ will only happen if $100 - G_n \ge 0$.

However, two questions remain, what is the distribution of $G_n$? (How do I derive the distribution of the sum of $n$ iid uniform random variables and second, how do I compute the infinite sum?

Comment: Asked and answered on MSE at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/763364/6179.